# How to show multiple images from my local machine at Shiny dashboard under multiple conditions

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I wish to show

```
if (reactive(input$id)() == condition_1) #id is the input variable
{
show image_1
}
if (reactive(input$id)() == condition_2)
{
show image_2
}
...

if (reactive(input$id)() == condition_n)
{
show image_n
}
```

I have tried in several ways but unable to perform it.

Comment: So, what happened then?

Comment: @JamesZ, used rederUI as the output function, there was no error message. Just showed a void space where the image should be.